# In OpenAPI, how to make some attributes required only in the PATCH?

Tags: rest, swagger, openapi

Imagine you have the object `User` (see below) which is used to specify the body param in both the calls `Post /users` and `Patch /users/:id`.

I want to use it for both API calls, but I need to specify that `firstname` and `lastname` are **not required in the `Patch` call**.

I know I could do that by duplicating the file `user.yaml` into another file (maybe called `patch_user.yml`) and removing the `required` section:

```
      required:
        - firstname
        - lastname
```

but I was wondering if there is a better way. I have the same issue in many endpoints, and I would end up with lots of duplication.

How would you tackle this problem?

---

`user.yaml`:

```
User
  type: object
  required:
    - type
    - attributes
  properties:
    id:
      type: string
    type:
      type: string
    attributes:
      type: object
      required:
        - firstname
        - lastname
      properties:
        firstname:
          type: string
          example: John
        lastname:
          type: string
          example: Doe
```

Comment: Instead of making firstName, lastName optional in PATCH, you can do the other way around. You can make the firstName, lastName params optional in your `user.yaml` file.
Then use the `allOf` technique to extend `user.yaml` for the POST request and make firstName, lastName required in the POST request. 

Docuemntation for `allOf` : https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/